# J1939 - Yamaha Rudder Position ADDRESS

Tags: codesys, addressing, j1939

Using a PCAN VIEW, I determined the "rudder position" address (Yamaha Outboard), to be ***166792448***, and using CAN_Rx_MessageProc_ST_0  got the outboard position from bytes 4 and 5 of the 8 byte array:

RUDDER_ANGLE_RAW := WORD_TO_INT((256*MESSAGE_RX_NMEA[5]) + MESSAGE_RX_NMEA[4]);

I assumed that this Address would stay constant, but when the outboard changed, the address also changed - new address was ***166792453***.  And further to this, after a power cycle, the address changed again to ***166792456***.

Assuming this has to do with address claiming, conflict, and the address changing.

The questions I have (and I have tried to grasp concepts but as a newby here am struggling) are thus:

1   Is there a range within in which this address will stay?

2   Can I get information out of the 8 byte received data (such as "yamaha outboard" or manufacturer specific info) that I could use to determine what the actual address is?

IF there is a range, I could write a procedure to scan the range, looking for the manufacturer ID, and thus determine the correct address.

Any help appreciated would be appreciated!

Comment: I know nothing about vehicle automation, but assuming that somthing stays in the same place in memory after a power cycle or reset is very bad. Memory is dynamic. I'd imagine that whatever writes that data into memory should have a way to tell you where it wrote

Comment: Hi, It's not about memory but rather address claiming on the canbus when system starts up. thanks